# Pagination does not work on Custom Post Type archive while trying to get load more function working

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

Im trying to get a load more function to work with a custom post type on an archive page.

I use this plugin and customized it a bit so it works with a custom post type.
http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

Currently pagination doesn't work so that the plugin can't load more items. It says "inbeeld/page/2/ 404 (Not Found)". So my question is why does the pagination do not work?

This is the register_post_type code.

```
$inbeeld_args = array(
    'label' => __('In Beeld'),
    'singular_label' => __('In Beeld'),
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "inbeeld", 'with_front'=> false, "pages" => true  ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'taxonomy', 'thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array('teams'),
    'add_new' => _x('Nieuw', 'In Beeld'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Voeg Nieuw In Beeld Toe'),
    'edit_item' => __('Bewerk In Beeld'),
    'new_item' => __('Nieuw In Beeld'),
    'view_item' => __('Bekijk In Beeld'),
    'search_items' => __('Doorzoek In Beeld'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No In Beeld found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No In Beeld found in Trash'),
    'pages' => true
);
register_post_type('inbeeld',$inbeeld_args);
```

And this is my loop. I removed some code that nothing has to do with my question.

```
<?php

$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_query(array('post_type' => 'inbeeld','paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 2  ));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
  <li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </li>     
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with pagination was fixed by removing the wp_query loop and using the normal loop.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The problem with the "load more" plugin was fixed by using the right classname to load the items. And change this in the php of the plugin.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;   
$args = array('post_type' => 'inbeeld', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') );    
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$max = $query->max_num_pages;
```